# Passing laravel old form data to Vue.js instance

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

2 weeks ago I found out i couldn't solve this and went to google for a solution which dind't really give me one, maybe the wrong type of googling not sure. Let me get to the point.

I got this piece of html and vue which makes dynamically a extra phone field when a button is pressed. the thing is when a Laravel validation fails i do not know how to get the old() data into Vue, so I can push that to the phone_number_field array.

```
<a v-on:click="addPhoneNumberField">
    <span class="panel-title glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
<a v-on:click="deletePhoneNumberField" v-if="phone_number_field.length > 0">
    <span class="panel-title glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>

<div class="phone row" v-for="(field, index) in phone_number_field">
    <input id="phone_number_number" type="text" class="form-control" :name="'customer[phone_numbers][' + index + '][number]'" placeholder="Number" required>
    <input id="phone_number_description" type="text" class="form-control" :name="'customer[phone_numbers][' + index + '][description]'" placeholder="Description">  
</div>
```

Vue part

```
var bindUser = new Vue({
    el: '#bindUser',

    data: {
        phone_number_field: [],
    },

    methods: {
        addPhoneNumberField() {
            this.phone_number_field.push({
                number: '',
                description: ''
            })
        },

        deletePhoneNumberField(index) {
            this.phone_number_field.splice(index, 1)
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: Is your page getting refresh everytime  ?

Comment: Why not using ajax to submit form ?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with JS in general and am more curious if this is possible with Vue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old values are inside `old('customer.phone_numbers')`, so just pass it encoded into vue initiating.

Your blade template (somewhere before js include):

```
<script>
   var phoneValues = {!! json_encode(old('customer.phone_numbers', [])) !!};
</script>
```

Your js file:

```
data: {
    phone_number_field: phoneValues,
},
```

Where `[]` is the default value. But I think it's better to have all the initiating code in one place (blade template).

Comment: This results into a syntax error

     phone_number_field: {!! json_encode(old('customer.phone_numbers', [])) !!},

I got the Vue instance in a seperate app.js

Comment: Well, you *have to* initiate vuejs app values in your blade template.  The rest logic can be in the js file.

Comment: So simple, thanks. this has been holding me back for a while.

Also most of the times i tried to declare it within my #bindUser div, but it has to be outside the div else Vue will throw a error

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea..
Why don't you do something along these lines:

```
let phone_number_field = [];
<?php if (!empty($_POST['phone_number_field']: ?>
    phone_number_field = []; //Loop foreach or whatever you need to build it
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then in VUE you can just initalize it with the prepouplated or empty phone_number_field you precreated

Comment: I tried setting values outside from the view instance (in blade template)
Can't get it to work.

Comment: @Cruorzy did you assign this variable before vue is instanced?

Comment: I did it before my vue instance was loaded/created but within the div that the vue instance focussed on, and in there you can't/shouldn't use script tags. But it works now :)